# Proper Inter-service authorization

Tags: authentication, architecture, authorization, microservices

My question is how to properly do inter-service authorization without breaking your application logic.

Example 1: You have a token based auth system set up which involves forwarding your auth token through an API Gateway and all your microservices in the call chain. Each microservice performs their own authorization logic based on the authenticated user identity.

Problem 1: How do you make sure authorization rules do not clash with each-other between the services? For example: service 1 has an endpoint: "placeOrder" which in turn invokes service 2's "transferFunds" and service 3's "getProductDetails". Now the given user identity is only authorized to use the "placeOrder" functionality of service 1 and this being a 0 trust environment the user has no access to the named service 2 and 3 endpoints but invoking these is still needed to complete the initial request in service 1.

Now one way to deal with this is with a temporary privilege escalation in service 1 to allow the invocation. But this in certain scenarios seems to defeat the purpose as suddenly every subsequent call in the chain is as a technical user who can perform anything and who knows what other services will be invoked indirectly in the chain.
I am wondering if there is a better solution which avoids the downsides while maintaining 0 trust between the services.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that the placeOrder endpoint invokes the transferFunds and getProductDetails, I'd suggest two kinds of permissions, DirectInvoke, and SystemInvoke.  DirectInvoke only needs a auth-token for the user, SystemInvoke needs a user identity and an auth-token generated by the originating upstream service.

You will have to provision the authorization for SystemInvoke for any downstream services that you will need to invoke.  This will of course create errors whilst you figure out your dependency map, but hopefully you can do this fairly quickly.  Alternatively you can blanket authorize all users for SystemInvoke but explicity revoke services you think they SHOULDN'T have access to.